# Different languages in a downloadable application

Tags: java, c

I would like your opinion on whether this idea sounds good to you, and if not, what you would do instead.

The goal of my project is to make a downloadable application that lets the user input a text file of experimental data, then performs calculations on the data to find statistical values such as the mean, standard deviation, and slope and intercept of the linear regression line. These are presented on the screen, as well as a scatter plot or histogram of the data.

For now, my plan has been to code the interface that the user interacts with in Java using the Swing library, and the part that performs the calculations in C. My reasons for doing this are that Java is good for GUIs that can be used on any machine, and C is faster at performing big calculations. One critical step in my project is to parallelize the code using the MPICH library so that my program can do things like make many sets of randomized data and analyze them. The Java and C code would communicate with each other by inputting and outputting text files, and I have been told that I need to do some shell scripting to bridge the two together. By doing this, I would hope that the Java code would give the C code the text file of the original data, the C code would do the calculations and report the statistical values in the form of a text file, and then the Java code would read this text file to present the results of data analysis to the user.

The important characteristics of this downloadable application are:

1. Has a very clear, easy-to-use interface
2. Can be downloaded and used easily, ideally on all kinds of computers (Windows, Mac, Linux)
3. Takes advantage of parallelization to do big calculations faster

I am not very knowledgeable about these languages or environments, and I am having a few doubts about my plan.

1. I know that Java programs are easily downloadable in a jar file, but if I use Java and C, will my program still be easily downloadable and able to be used on all machines with the shell scripting?
2. Would it be best to do all my coding in one language and still preserve the important characteristics listed above? If so, what would I be losing by doing so compared to using two languages?

I appreciate your help!

Comment: "The part that performs the calculations in C" and your #2, "ideally on all kinds of computers (Windows, Mac, Linux)" are mutually exclusive. C [-compiled executable] programs do not work cross-platform without recompiling (which counteracts your "used easily").

Answer (score 1):

Please read again quotes from your own post:

First

> I am not very knowledgeable about these languages

But:

> Java is good for GUIs

And

> Java is good for GUIs

So, you do not really have knowledge in Java and C but you can state that Java is good for GUI and C is faster. But both statements are probably wrong.

For the last 15 years people tend to avoid implementing SWING UI and desktop applications in java. They typically try to move the calculations to server and control the process using web based UI. (This probably is not applicable for your use-case if you have indeed large input data sets, e.g. tens or hundreds of GB).

During the same period JVM was significantly improved in terms of performance, so assumption that C code runs faster than the same code written in java could be incorrect.

So, probably you should implement all in java.

If you cannot move the calculations to server you can implement java application and run it using JNLP.

However before you start, may I recommend you to ask other design/architecture question that will contain more details about the amount of your input/output data and the nature of your calculations?

Answer (score 0):

Let's address your characteristics first.

1. This is debatable, but I would make the claim that while certain languages make clean UI's easier, it is possible to make a good UI in any popular language with proper library support.
2. Portability - If you are planning to distribute in *binary* form and not in source form, then Java wins hands down. If you are planning to distribute in *source* form then `C` is possible but you will have to provide a means of building the application on each platform, which will usually be different for each platform.
3. Performance through parallel computation. For your kind of application (CPU Bound), C will likely be faster, but the difference may not matter enough for you to care.

Now let's talk about your doubts.

1. This is addressed in (2) above.
2. A single-language program is generally easier to maintain and distribute. You will lose a lot of headache by not dealing with two languages. You might also lose some performance if you choose only Java, but you will lose no portability if you choose only C vs C and Java, since the C part will already be non-portable.